# Weird LWC Error on template if:true

Tags: lightning-web-components, error

```
<template if:true={isMultiEntry}>TRUE {isMultiEntry} </template>
It displays on the page as: TRUE false
```

This is launched from an Aura Wrapper component in a button on a record detail page. There are errors on loading the page itself, but none on launching the component.

There are errors on the page but, but based on the stack traces, none point to my component. Also, all are generated before launching my component (my component does not generate any errors) and there are no LWCs that are present on the page outside of an aura-wrapper button.

Errors on the page load itself are:

- Error: [LWC error]: The `insertBefore` method is available only on elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive.
- Error: [LWC error]: The `replaceChild` method is available only on elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive.
- Error: [LWC error]: The `appendChild` method is available only on
  elements that use the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive.
- Error: [LWC error]: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched
  in element . Event name must 1) Start
  with a lowercase letter 2) Contain only lowercase letters, numbers,
  and underscores
- Uncaught (in promise) Error: getAllTabInfo() - Failed to get tabInfo.

Comment: Do you have the `Enable Debug Mode for Lightning Components.` turned on?

Comment: Yes. Apparently, I need longer comments than 4 chars so this is just filler.

Comment: What do you mean by this is just filler? 

Anyhow since turning on `Debug Mode` I started seeing the same errors that you are seeing and they are being related to SF components. Just like you the errors and the stack trace have nothing to do with my components. I just ignore those errors. If you turn off the Debug Mode those errors will likely disappear from your console.

Comment: stack exchange has a minimum comment length. Agreed those other errors are probably meaningless, I just didn't know what it could be so I threw them in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Errors in console:

All those errors are because of errors in the way standard LWC components are handled in Aura context or vice versa. These have been there (some added/fixed in major releases) from long time and we see them in **debug** mode.

Note that errors in console for standard components will not really affect your implementation. These errors are custom errors generated by LWC layer handler and apparently few standard LWC components are not in-line with best practices/way of implementation

#### Component problem

`isMultiEntry` is setting to String `'false'` and so it is showing up. `isMultiEntry` should be boolean `false`.

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying that the errors are being displayed because `isMultiEntry` is being set to a String instead of a Boolean?

Comment: @Arthlete sry for confusion, modified answer

Comment: No worries at all I just wanted to confirm, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Ummm.....why don't they fix that bug? It's horribly ugly and pollutes the console. While they're at it, could they please remove all the other junk emitted on the console when in debug mode which is completely useless to developers? If they want to see their own debug messages then let them define their own internal debug setting.